# Writing Mocha Chai Test cases for NodeJs Controllers

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, testing, mocha.js, chai

I am new to unit testing. I am trying to write test cases for controller.js files for nodejs microservices files. I am unable to understand where I am going wrong. Always throws an error "TypeError: Cannot read property 'empId' of undefined" for 2 of these properties.

This is the controller code:

```
const crmgDetails = db.crmgResource_details;
const employeeProposal = db.employee_Proposal;
const Op = db.Sequelize.Op;
const raDetails = db.crmgRaSheet_entity;
let results = [];
Sequelize = require('sequelize')

exports.findOne = (req, res) => {
    console.log(req.body.empId);
    crmgDetails.findAll({where: {
        resEmployeeNumber: req.body.empId
    }
    })
       .then(data => {
           res.send(data);
        })
        .catch(err => {
            res.status(500).send({
                message:
                    err.message || "Some error occurred while retrieving tutorials."
      });
    });
};

exports.findMatchingDemandsForRmg = (req,res) => {
    let proposedDemands = [];
    
    employeeProposal.findAll({
        where: {
            emp_id: req.body.empId,
            demandSbu : req.body.sbu
        }
    }).then(proposedEmployee => {
        console.log('proposedEmployee',proposedEmployee);
        if(proposedEmployee.length === 0){
            crmgDetails.findAll({
                where: {
                    resEmployeeNumber: req.body.empId,
                    demandSbu: req.body.sbu
                }
            }).then(matchingDemands => {
                
                console.log('matchingDemands  ',matchingDemands)
                proposedDemands = matchingDemands;
                
            })
        }
        else{
            console.log("crmg Employee")
            console.log(proposedEmployee)
            
            
                for(let employee of proposedEmployee){
                
                        crmgDetails.findOne({
                            where: {
                                demandUid: employee.demandUid,
                                resEmployeeNumber: req.body.empId,
                                demandSbu: req.body.sbu
                            }
                        }).then( crmgProposed=> {
                            proposedDemands.push(crmgProposed);
                        })
                
                    
                }
            
        }
        setTimeout(() => {
            console.log(proposedDemands)
        res.send(proposedDemands);
        }, 3000);
        
        
    }).catch((err)=>{
        res.status(500).send({
            message:
              err.message || "Some error occurred while retrieving tutorials."
          });
    })

}

exports.getResourceAllocationDetails = (req,res) => {
    employeeProposal.findAll({
        include: {
            model: raDetails
        },
        where: Sequelize.and(
            {activeFlag : true},
            Sequelize.or({status:"Accepted By RMG"},
            {status:"Rejected"}
        ))
    }).then(employees => {
        res.send(employees)
    })
}
```

This is the test file I tried to write without my head:

```
const CrmgRaSheetModel = require('../controllers/crmgResource_Details.controller')
describe('Check for succcessful fetech API call', () => {
  it('property getResourceAllocationDetails should be called', async () => {
    CrmgRaSheetModel.getResourceAllocationDetails((res) => {
      expect(res).to.be.an('object')
              return res.json()
          })
  });
  it('property findMatchingDemandsForRmg should be called', async () => {
    CrmgRaSheetModel.findMatchingDemandsForRmg((res) => {
      expect(res).to.be.an('object')
              return res.json()
          })
  });
  it('property findOne should be called', async () => {
    CrmgRaSheetModel.findOne((res) => {
      expect(res).to.be.an('object')
              return res.json()
          })
  })
})
```

Comment: You need to set up a mock API call.

Answer (score 0):

from test file you are calling controller method with only res, so no chance to send your input as your body.
So pass req,res both and pass your input value in req